# embedded gist file word-wrap

Tags: word-wrap, gist

I've embedded a gist file on my webpage, and it contains some long lines of code which require quite a bit of horizontal scrolling to fully view.

Is there some way to enable word wrap for embedded gist files, so that no horizontal scroll-bar will be present?

Answer (score 1):

You could force word wrapping with CSS.

```
.gist .blob-code-inner {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Comment: I needed to add `!important`. Also the scroll-bar is still there for long words. Is there a way to achieve a `word-wrap: break-word;`-like behaviour?